# CoreData - optional field and a regexp?

Tags: regex, xcode, core-data

I have a field containing an e-mail address in my model and I validate the address with a regular expression. This field is optional, but the regexp check is triggered even if the value is null.

Is there any clean way to disable the check on an empty value or should I just wrap the regexp in `()?`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about disabling, but it's easy enough to use alternation:

```
/^|your-original-regex$/
```